# In VS 2003, how to suppress deployment of .NET CF 1.0 every time I debug?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, visual-studio-2003, .net-1.0

I'm (unfortunately) using VS 2003 to develop for some Windows CE .NET 4.1 mobile devices. The app is written in .NET Compact Framework 1.0 (the OS cannot support any later version of the .NET CF).

Whenever I run my app from Visual Studio, it copies/tries to install .NET CF 1.0 to my device:

```
Copying netcf.all.wce4.armv4t.cab
```

It takes a very long time to copy, and then finally the device asks me if I want to re-install (I always say 'no').

Since this takes such a long time to copy, I would ideally like to instruct VS 2003 to **not** copy the file every time I hit 'debug'. Is there any way to change my deployment settings in this way?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have Studio '03 installed on anything any longer, but let's see if it works like '08.

First, look in the project properties.  In the "Devices" section, see if there is a checkbox that says something like "Deploy the latest version of the COmpact Framework".

If not, then we can try the back door *if* it uses the same mechanism that '08 uses to deploy (and I think it may).  Try the following:

- Shut down all instances of Studio
- Make a backup copy of %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\CoreCon\1.0\Microsoft.NetCF.1.0.xsl
- Now delete that file, or open it and comment out the FILES in the FILECONTAINER that's pushing the framework.

You might have to do the same in the "All Users" profile folder as well.

Again, make sure you back up these files before editing.

Comment: Worked perfectly! The location on my XP install, though, was __C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\visualstudio\devices\addons__.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project (in the explorer window) and click Settings, then click the Devices tab.  Uncheck the box labeled "Deploy the latest version of the .NET Compact Framework etc. etc.".